# Get Temporary folder in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I am using ***System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()*** in my WCF service to create a temp file in the temp folder path in IIS.
I was expecting to get ***C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp*** path but I am getting ***C:\Windows\Temp instead***.

How can I get the expected path?

Comment: It's very likely that your application pool in IIS is not running under your local account (hence getting a different folder). Per default, IIS use special limited accounts for security reasons: https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of Kernel32.dll:GetTempPath() might help you:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx

basically what's happening is IIS is running under an account that doesn't have a USERPROFILE env variable defined, so its using either TMP or TEMP instead.

Remember, w3wp (worker process in IIS) usually runs as DefaultAppPool and not as an actual user with a directory assigned.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
//This code is you need, this code is getting current user temp directory.
string temp = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
//This method is getting system temp directory.
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```

Comment: But what is the current user? Read the comment of Kevin Gosse.